# Stripe - No API key provided?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm struggling with this error No API key provided. Set your API key using "Stripe.api_key = ". You can generate API keys from the Stripe web interface in a Rails app after following step by step [Stripe's guide](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails).

From what I see, everything looks fine, but it keeps returning that notice. Any advice?

Charges Controller:

```
  class ChargesController < ApplicationController

    def new
    end

    def create
      # Amount in cents
      @amount = 500

      customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
        :email => 'example@stripe.com',
        :card  => params[:stripeToken]
      )

      charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :customer    => customer.id,
        :amount      => @amount,
        :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
        :currency    => 'usd'
      )

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to charges_path
    end

  end
```

config/initializers/stripe.rb

```
    Rails.configuration.stripe = {
      :publishable_key => ENV['pk_test_KEY'],
      :secret_key      => ENV['sk_test_KEY']
    }

    Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

Terminal trace
        Started POST "/charges" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-12 22:15:08 +0100

```
    Processing by ChargesController#create as HTML

      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XXX", "stripeToken"=>"tok_1590kf2NNSl5uX0kXE9XXX", "stripeTokenType"=>"card", "stripeEmail"=>"USER@gmail.com"}

    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms



    Stripe::AuthenticationError - No API key provided. Set your API key using "Stripe.api_key = <API-KEY>". You can generate API keys from the Stripe web interface. See https://stripe.com/api for details, or email support@stripe.com if you have any questions.:

       () Users/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/stripe-ruby-9c7ebd21c973/lib/stripe.rb:71:in `request'

       () Users/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/stripe-ruby-9c7ebd21c973/lib/stripe/api_operations/create.rb:6:in `create'

       () Users/javier/Desktop/definitive/app/controllers/charges_controller.rb:10:in `create'
```

Tested including the keys in secrets.yml as @sealocal suggests in comments, but still the same issue:

```
development:
 secret_key_base: key
 publishable_key: anotherkey
 secret_key: anotherkey

test:
 secret_key_base:key
production:
 secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
 publishable_key: <%= ENV["publishable_key"] %>
 secret_key: <%= ENV["secret_key"] %>
```

Comment: Are those your real keys? I don't think you want `ENV['pk_test_NYW7gGgMYnx4HznUXLyti5r3']`. If you are hard coding in the values, just put the `'pk_test_NYW7gGgMYnx4HznUXLyti5r3'`.

Comment: Former keys, not in use anymore. Tested but it keeps returning the same notice.

Comment: Where are you storing your Stripe keys? You should have a file that sets your ENV variables. What does it look like?

Comment: @sealocal in config/initializers/stripe.rb, is that not right?

Comment: @malditojavi I don't think you're doing it the right way. I think my answer might help you out.

Comment: Are you trying to get this working in your development environment (i.e. localhost)?

Comment: Got it in localhost, and production (Heroku). Both same issue.

Answer (score 7):

You need to store your Stripe keys in environment variables so that `config/initializers/stripe.rb` can read them.

In Rails 4.1+ you can use [`secrets.yml`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#config-secrets-yml):

```
development:
  secret_key_base: key
  publishable_key: pk_test_lkasjdflkajsd
  secret_key: sk_test_lkasjdflkajsd
```

NOTE: Use exactly two spaces when defining nested key-value pairs in YAML.  That is, the keys under `development` should be indented by two spaces, and not with a tab character. This is because YAML files strictly depend on indentation.

In `config/initializers/stripe.rb`:

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => Rails.application.secrets.publishable_key,
  :secret_key      => Rails.application.secrets.secret_key
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

Comment: Tested, updated in the comments with the code I'm including, but still the same issue.

Comment: If you're using `secrets.yml` you have to access your secrets with this syntax: `Rails.application.secrets.publishable_key`. Updated answer to show what your `stripe.rb` should look like.  Your code in the question doesn't show that you've used that syntax. Does that help?

Comment: If I understood it well, you suggest to include  publishable_key: Rails.application.secrets.publishable_key in my secrets.yml? That does not work neither.

Comment: No, that call should go in your `stripe.rb` file.  The point I was trying to make is that in your `stripe.rb` you have a line that looks like this: `:publishable_key => ENV['pk_test_KEY']`, but you should be using `Rails.application.secrets.pk_test_key` in place of `ENV['pk_test_key']`.  It doesn't matter if you use the name `pk_test_key` or `publishable_key`, as long they match between your `stripe.rb` and `secrets.yml`.

Comment: @malditojavi I updated the answer to only use `secrets.yml` so that my suggestion is more clear.

Comment: If that still does not solve the problem, try stopping your local server, run `$ spring stop`, and then `$ rails s` to start again.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 7, open your credentials file from your terminal:

```
$ EDITOR="code --wait" rails credentials:edit --environment=development
```

Feel free to remove --enviroment=development if you want to use the credentials in all your environments, or pass specific ones for the ones you need: --environment=production...

You can also swap 'code' for 'vim' or 'mate' in EDITOR.

In your credentials file:

```
stripe:
  publishable_key: pk_whateverYourPublishableKeyFromStripeDashboard
  secret_key: sk_whateverYourSecretKeyFromStripeDashboard
```

Now close this file and head to:

```
# config/initializers/stripe.rb
Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:stripe, :secret_key)

# create the file if you don't have one.
```

Restart your server, you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Stripe support replied my email and their solution is working fine:

**config/initializers/stripe.rb**

```
 Rails.configuration.stripe = { 
  :publishable_key => 'pk_test_thekey', 
  :secret_key => 'sk_test_thekey'
}   ﻿
```

Also part of their answer *It looks like you are trying to set your API key to an ENV variable named after your key, which is likely not a valid key. You will want to change it to ENV['NAME_OF_ENV_VAR_HERE'], or simply access the key directly, like the lines included above*